# how default static inner class can be accessed from test internally

Tags: spring

It sounds like a silly question but I was wondering why the default static inner class `YN` in `User` class in `main` directory can be accessed by `UserTest` in `test` directory.

I know the default access modifier can access in the same package but `main` and `test` directory seem different yet how it can access the default class internally?

```
package com.microservice.user.domain;

public class User {

    static enum YN{
        Y, N;
    }

}
```

```
package com.microservice.user.domain;

class UserTest {

    @Test
    void user_test() {
        User user = User.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .marketAgree(User.YN.Y)
                .build();

    }
```

Comment: Make inner static enum as public to access outside

Comment: They are in the same package, that they are in a different directory doesn't matter.

Comment: @M.Deinum so even though `main` and `test` are physically different directory, yet Spring treats that `User` and `UserTest` are in **the same name package** (`com.microservice.user.domain`). is it correct?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring that is just how java works. It is the package that counts not the directories.

Comment: @M.Deinum right, I was too obsessed with Spring. thank you for your comments!